# Imagick - set paper size of output pdf

Tags: php, imagick

I have a php helper function that takes base64 png and outputs a pdf file:

```
    public static function base64PngToPdf($b64, $filePath) {
        $imagick = new Imagick();
        $imagick->readImageBlob(base64_decode($b64));

        // Create PDF File
        $pdfFile = new Imagick();
        $pdfFile->setFormat('pdf');
        // Add image to pdf
        $pdfFile->addImage($imagick->getImage());

        file_put_contents($filePath, $pdfFile->getImagesBlob());
        return $filePath;
    }
```

The problem in my case is, the png I have is 800w x 1200h px. The code above is outputting a label that's 211 x 317mm. I want to get a label that's scaled down to either 101mm wide or 152mm tall (preferrably without scaling the pixels themselves, just changing the physical size).

I did some googling and found the imagick has a density parameter, but I'm not 100% sure if that's what I want in this case, and my library doesn't have a `->setDensity` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sort-of related solution. I can use `$pdfFile->setResolution($resolution[0], $resolution[1]);`, and in `setResolution` I can set for example a ppi of 72.